# Tensorflow tfrecord not being read correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm trying to use Tensorflow to train a CNN on my own segmentation data set. Based on my research, tfRecords seemed to be the best way to go. I've figured out how to write to and read from a tfRecord database, but absolutely nothing I try successfully reads it within a Tensorflow graph. Here is a snippet that successfully reconstructs images and ground truth from my database:

```
data_path = 'Training/train.tfrecords'  # address to save the hdf5 file

record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=data_path)
reconstructed_images = []
reconstructed_groundtruths = []
count = 0
for string_record in record_iterator:
  example = tf.train.Example()
  example.ParseFromString(string_record)
  height = int(example.features.feature['height']
                             .int64_list
                             .value[0])

  width = int(example.features.feature['width']
                            .int64_list
                            .value[0])

  gt_string = (example.features.feature['train/groundTruth']
                              .bytes_list
                              .value[0])

  image_string = (example.features.feature['train/image']
                            .bytes_list
                            .value[0])

  img_1d = np.fromstring(image_string, dtype=np.uint8)
  reconstructed_img = img_1d.reshape((height, width))
  gt_1d = np.fromstring(gt_string, dtype=np.uint8)
  reconstructed_gt = gt_1d.reshape((height, width))

  reconstructed_images.append(reconstructed_img)
  reconstructed_groundtruths.append(reconstructed_gt)
  count += 1
```

This code succeeds in giving me a list of numpy arrays for the images and ground truth labels in my database. Now, to attempt to actually train something, I am working from the MNIST example which you can find [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py).

I have replaced the decode function with the following:

```
def decode(serialized_example):

  features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
    features={
      'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([1],tf.int64),
      'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([1],tf.int64),
      'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'train/groundTruth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    })


  height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int64)
  width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int64)
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.uint8)
  image.set_shape((height,width))
  gt = tf.decode_raw(features['train/groundTruth'], tf.uint8)
  gt.set_shape((height,width))


  return image, gt
```

When I run it, there are multiple problems that indicate the code just plain fails to read the database. As written above, I will get an error on the line parsing `height`, which states

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'Tensor'

If I temporarily just set the `height` and `width` to literals, I get an error on the image parsing line that says

> Shapes (?,) and (512, 512) are not compatible

It is obvious that this means the images were not correctly read from the database, but I have absolutely no idea why or how to fix it. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by sheer luck. Apparently,

```
image.set_shape((height,width))
```

Should be

```
image = tf.reshape(image,(height,width,1))
```

And similar for gt. I have no idea why the Tensorflow tutorial I was following uses set_shape... all I can guess is that it works for 1d but not for 2d or more? I can see now that it also isn't a tensor function, so it can't use graph-dependent variables like height, but that alone doesn't explain why it didn't work when I replaced (height,width) with global constants. Would appreciate further clarification if anyone knows.